# How to get CSV file from URL with authentication in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm working on a project on physionet.I have physionet credentials also.
I'm trying to get csv file directly into my python notebook instead of downloading it into my local machine.
I tried many ways but all are giving me 403.
I tried with User-Agent as well but it didn't work.
Anyone can suggest someway to do it.

```
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
url = 'https://physionet.org/files/nch-sleep/3.1.0/'
requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('username', 'pass'))
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: 403 means forbidden not 401 for unauthorized. Maybe the URL requires a payload or parameters. Can you fetch the CSV file on your local machine with the same code?

Comment: Are those your actual credentials? If so - you should change them now...

Answer (score -1):

if this is an HTML login, i dont think you would be able to mimic with requests call unless you know all the request header parameters, even though you provide username&password. if you want really an API call for your login, you need to hit the actual login api endpoint with basic auth credentials and tokens and with the response token,  hit your actual endpoint to read your csv files.